# Find the angle using two 3d position vectors

Tags: vectors, triangles, angle

I hope this makes sense because I am not really good with vectors. But imagine I have two $3$-dimensional position vectors at points $A(2i + 3j + 3k)$ and $B(5i + j + 4k)$. Then imagine a straight line $c$ goes from point $A$ to point $B$ then I use the line $c$ to form the hypotenuse of a right angle triangle. How can I measure the angle in the triangle?

Remember this is is all in $3$D.

Comment: One of the angles is right, this is all you can say. (Actually, you left the triangle undefined.)

Comment: In two dimensions, you could say that you want one leg of the right triangle to be parallel to the $x$ axis and another leg parallel to the $y$ axis. With that restriction, there are only two choices for the third vertex of the triangle, and the triangles you get for each of those choices are congruent, so you can just pick one of the triangles and measure its angles. In three dimensions you might require one leg to be parallel to the $z$ axis and one leg parallel to the $x,y$ plane, but there are other sets of requirements, just as good as these, producing triangles with different angles.

Answer (score 2):

The vector from A to B is AB = B-A = (3i -2j + k). So you know 3 vectors OA, OB and AB. You can find the angle $\theta$ between any two vectors using the dot product formula
$$X.Y=|X||Y|\cos(\theta)$$
so
$$\theta=\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{X.Y}{|X||Y|}\right)$$
However, I am not clear where the third vertex in your right angled triangle is. No pair of vectors from the vectors you have is at right angles to one another, otherwise their dot product would be 0.